# 3 sine wave amplitude 120 degrees

Tags: trigonometry

Preamble: an apology.

I have a limited knowledge of mathematics. I know basic trigonometry, and use a lot of maths professionally as a programmer - but all of it basic maths. I know my sines and cosines, exponents etc, but am lost when it comes to differential calculus. I don't know the jargon, and I don't know my $\alpha$ from my $\omega$ (in mathematics). I am on math.stackexchange, asking a question, because I don't know the answer to a question I have. Not only do I not know the answer, I do not know how to ask the question. That being said, I'm a quick study, if you can point me in the right direction, I can figure out what I'm missing.

If a person like that is not welcome here, go ahead and say so, and I will find somewhere else.

The context: what I have, and where it came from.

I am doing some electronics as a hobby (though this is NOT an electronics question!). As part of this, I am measuring voltages put out by a 3-phase generator. The motor has 3 coils, offset at $120^\circ$. The voltage across a single coil depends on where the coil is relative to the magnet, and the speed. The formula for a given coil is: $V=a \times sin(\alpha)$, where V is the voltage across a coil (which I can measure), a is the speed of rotation, and $\alpha$ is the angle relative to the magnets.

I can find out the voltage across the 3 coils, and since they are offset at 120 degrees, they MUST always add up to 0.

This is what it looks like, for an amplitude of 1:
[image: 3 phase waveform]

So, I know the 3 voltages $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$, and would like to know the angle between $coil_1$ and the magnets, and the speed (in arbitrary units). A second sample can then tell me a second angle, which will tell me which way the generator is rotating. The speed and direction will vary from sample to sample. The generator will always be rotating sufficiently slow that I am guaranteed to get more than 2 measurements before it turns 180 degrees.

So my question is:

If I know the following:

- the values of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$
- $v_1=a \times sin(\alpha)$
- $v_2=a \times sin(\alpha + 120^\circ)$
- $v_3=a \times sin(\alpha + 240^\circ)$

how can I calculate the value of a and/or $\alpha$ ? If I know one, the other is pretty trivial.

For example, if I tell you that $v_1$=0.172, $v_2$=2.630, $v_3$=-2.802, how would you work it out?

What I have worked out so far:

- $v_1 + v_2 + v_3 = 0$
- There is a unique answer for the angle, given the proportions of $v_1$, $v_2$ and $v_3$.
- If $v_1$ is the largest, we are at an angle between $30^\circ$ and $150^\circ$, a similar segment applies to the other two being the largest. This can also be the smallest (most negative) number, dividing the circle into $60^\circ$ segments.
- If necessary, I can work out the answer (for a given set of values) in code, using successive approximations, but this feels very unsatisfactory, in addition to not learning anything new (which I think is valuable in itself).
- I could also work out a reasonable approximation with a lookup table. It would only need to cover a $60^\circ$ segment, containing the ratio of the largest of the 3 values, to the second largest.
- I can get an approximation of the amplitude: $\frac{abs(v_1)+abs(v_2)+abs(v_3)}{1+sin(120^\circ)}$, which is within 8% of the correct value
- Once I know the amplitude, $\alpha = sin^{-1}(v_1/a)$
- If I know the angle, $a = v_1/sin(\alpha)$

I don't know what to put as a title, or as tags (except trigonometry). If I knew the correct terminology, I would just look that up and find the answer.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr), and please show some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the angle sum formula
$$v_2=a\sin(\alpha + 120^\circ)\\=a\sin \alpha \cos 120^\circ+a\cos \alpha \sin 120^\circ\\=v_1\cos 120^\circ+v_1\sin120^\circ \cot \alpha\\
\cot \alpha=\frac {v_2-v_1\cos 120^\circ}{v_1\sin 120^\circ}\\
\alpha=\operatorname{arccot} \left(\frac {v_2-v_1\cos 120^\circ}{v_1\sin 120^\circ}\right)$$

Answer (score 1):

Just try to prove that  $$v_1+v_2+v_3=0.$$
It says that if $v_1+v_2+v_3\neq0$ then it's impossible.

Otherwise, we can solve the system:
$$v_1=a\sin{x}$$ and $$v_2=a\sin(x+120^{\circ}).$$

We have
$$-\frac{1}{2}\sin{x}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cos{x}=\frac{v_2}{a}$$
$$\sin{x}=\frac{v_1}{a},$$
which gives $$\cos{x}=\frac{\frac{2v_2}{a}+\frac{v_1}{a}}{\sqrt3}$$
and use $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1.$

Comment: Looks like OP seeks how to find $a,x$ where your equation is *assumed* to hold.

Comment: It says that it's  impossible.

Comment: What is the "it" of "It says..."?

Comment: It's impossible sometimes. I added something to my post.

Comment: Michael: I was just curious what software said the vectors sum to zero. [Likely it's a simple trig identity anyway, but I was asking about what software you happened to use (if any), might be useful...]

Comment: I just used myself.

Comment: I have rephrased the question, and added an example.

Comment: I see you just "used myself," i.e. applied a trig identity. So with the added example I'll upvote it. +1

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I'm sorry, I still don't understand. Can you show the working for the v1, v2 and v3 I've given, as an example?